# spring jmx change property files

Tags: java, spring, jmx

Is there a Spring JMX example to change configuration properties dynamically.

Comment: Your question is vague. Please give an example of the sort of thing you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Spring Recipes" is a great source:

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-jmx.html